# How can I create two groups of radio buttons in a HTML form and when change in A Group will change in B Group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I Need to create two forms with radio buttons as following bellow and then, when change checked, I need to change automatically in the second form (jquery or javacript):

```
<form id="form-a" name="form-a">
    <input type="radio" name="name-a" id="id-a" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" name="name-b" id="id-b" value="No" />
</form>
<form id="form-b" name="form-b">
    <input type="radio" name="name-c" id="id-c" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" name="name-d" id="id-d" value="No" />
</form>
```

Comment: You means to say when if `name_a` is checked  in form `form_a` then it should also be checked in `form_b` as well for same value type like `Yes`?

Comment: Yes, when check name-a inf form-a check name-c in form_b
And when check name-b in form-a check name-d in form_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `name` attribute values on the radio buttons to group them and then just add an event listener to listen for changes.

Here is an example.

```js
var radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

function radioChangeHndl(evt) {
  radioBtns.forEach(function(radioBtn) {
    radioBtn.checked = '';
    if(radioBtn.value === this.value) {
      radioBtn.checked = 'true'
    }
  }.bind(this))
}

radioBtns.forEach(function(radioBtn) {
  radioBtn.addEventListener('change', radioChangeHndl);
});
```

```html
<form id="form-a" name="form-a">
  <input type="radio" name="name-a" id="id-a" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="name-b" id="id-b" value="No" />
</form>
<form id="form-b" name="form-b">
  <input type="radio" name="name-c" id="id-c" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="name-d" id="id-d" value="No" />
</form>
```

Comment: I can't change the name values because is a form to send values to a mailchimp form.

I can only "add class".... if this solution works with class I can try it, but the actual code do not works for me :( 
http://codepen.io/uzielweb/pen/gwxqyr

Comment: This is not my code example in the codepen. Do you need the `checked` attribute on the radio buttons as well ?

Comment: I have made an update on my answer, using the exact same html you posted.

Comment: Sorry ---- my mistake :)
Works when I use Jquery script load :)

Comment: This script is re-edit now. 
I am using Jquery with document.ready function :) .
Thank You!

Comment: I just saw that you edited my answer adding jQuery to the example. I rejected the edit, because jQuery is not needed for the above example. It is just plain vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed the HTML and JS. Know you just have to add the classes to the Radiobuttons. Tsted with Firefox, Chrome and IE 11. Maybe its not working because jquery is not loaded? If you Add jquery in the Javascript-Part, its working.

My solution is working in both ways. Click on form-a and form-b

HTML:
I changed the button names for grouping. JQuery selector is the classname i added.

```
<body onload="bodyLoad()">
    <form id="form-a" name="form-a">
    <input type="radio" class="radioA" name="name-a" id="id-a" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" class="radioB" name="name-b" id="id-b" value="No" />
</form>
<form id="form-b" name="form-b">
    <input type="radio" class="radioA" name="name-c" id="id-c" value="Yes" checked="checked" />
    <input type="radio" class="radioB" name="name-d" id="id-d" value="No" />
</form>
```

JS:
I decided to use click event.

```
function bodyLoad () {
$("input:radio").click(function() {
       var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
       $("input:radio").prop('checked',false);
       $("." + myClass).prop('checked',true);
});}
```